# Edit category lay-out, but apply parts to products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've got a custom category view.phtml for this category:
http://www.touchfix.nl/onderdelen

The sub-categories use their parent's XML-update, which is:

```
<reference name="catalog_category_default">
<reference name="content">
<remove name="category.products" />
<block type="catalog/category_view" name="alphabase.parts" template="catalog/category/view.parts.phtml">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.parts.phtml"></block>
</block>
</reference>
</reference>

<reference name="right">
<remove name="cms_waaromkiezen" />
<block type="cms/block" name="block_speerpunten_onderdelen">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_speerpunten_onderdelen</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>

<reference name="head">
<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/categoryblocks.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
```

I want to achieve that the changes to "right" are also applied to products in these categories.
But when I apply these changes to products too in category settings, the "content" reference screws up my page and it returns a blank page.

How can I reference the catalog_category view, so that the "content" update is only done when in category view and not in product view?

Answer (score 0):

catalog_category_default isn't a reference, it's a handle

have you tried changing to:

```
<catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: Nope, still screws up the category view, also returns nothing but:
frontend/default/site/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
frontend/base/default/template/catalog/msrp/popup.phtml

Comment: Please see my answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do the trick with the following:

```
<reference name="content">
    <reference name="category.products">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/view.repair.phtml</template></action>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/list.repair.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</reference>

<reference name="right">
    <remove name="cms_waaromkiezen" />
    <block type="cms/block" name="block_speerpunten_reparatie">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_speerpunten_reparatie</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>

<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/categoryblocks.css</stylesheet></action>
</reference>
```

The difference was not to delete the blocks and add new ones with the correct template, but to change the template files of the corresponding items. I can now also refer to the product view block with `<reference name="product.info">`, which will be my next step.